How to convert a CompletableFuture to a synchronous Flux stream
I'm using BedRock AI SDK of Java, the stream function is this:
    default CompletableFuture<Void> converseStream(Consumer<ConverseStreamRequest.Builder> converseStreamRequest, ConverseStreamResponseHandler asyncResponseHandler) {
    return this.converseStream((ConverseStreamRequest)((ConverseStreamRequest.Builder)ConverseStreamRequest.builder().applyMutation(converseStreamRequest)).build(), asyncResponseHandler);
}

And I converted the return of this function here:
        return Flux.create(sink -> {
        ConverseStreamResponseHandler responseHandler = ConverseStreamResponseHandler.builder()
                .subscriber(ConverseStreamResponseHandler.Visitor.builder()
                        .onContentBlockDelta(chunk -> {
                            try {
                                CustomClass chunk = convertToCustomClass(chunk);
                                sink.next(customClass);
                            } catch (Exception e) {
                                sink.error(e);
                            }
                        }).build()
                ).build();

        try {
            client.converseStream(
                    request -> request.modelId(converseRequest.modelId())
                            .messages(converseRequest.messages())
                            .inferenceConfig(converseRequest.inferenceConfig()),
                    responseHandler
            );
        } catch (Exception e) {
            sink.error(e);
        }
    });

In the code that follows, I want the converted Flux to be synchronous for ease of processing, but it seems that the converted Flux is asynchronous by the way I'm doing it.
For Azure SDK, the converted out is synchronous:
    return Flux.create(sink -> {
        IterableStream<ChatCompletions> responseStream = openAIClient.getChatCompletionsStream(
                aiModel.getDeploymentName(), convertRequest(chatCompletionRequest));

        responseStream.forEach(completion -> {
            CustomClass chunk = this.convertToCustomClass(completion);
            sink.next(chunk);
        });

        sink.complete();
    });

I'd like to know how to get BedRock's converted to synchronous as well? Thank you.

I got one thing wrong, whether Flux is synchronous or not depends on the person himself, in my question, IterableStream is synchronous and CompletableFuture is asynchronous, so the question should be how to convert CompletableFuture to synchronous (e.g.: IterableStream?) and then stuff it into the Flux
